# Open in explorer not working in ie 11 with O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am getting the below error, when using Open with Explorer option in my O365 site.

> We’re having trouble opening this library in File Explorer. Syncing this >library will give you a better experience.

Security settings in the browser is disabled, so i am not able to do anything on that.Got a thread https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2629108, but there is no solution for ie 11 browser. Also tried using Developer options and changing the browser options, but no hope.And last but not least its a 32 bit Windows 7 machine with 32 bit browser

Please help me in fixing the issue.